# HTTP password setup on mod_register_web ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd

I have configured mod_register_web module in ejabberd in the following way.. added configurations in listen part

> ```
> {5281, ejabberd_http, [
>    %%tls,                              %% currently https not implemented
>    %%{certfile, "/etc/ejabberd/certificate.pem"},
>    {request_handlers, [
>        {["register"], mod_register_web}
>    ]}
> ]},
> ```

Added module in modules part

> {mod_register_web, []}

then tried

> `http://localhost:5281/register/`

and page becomes available without any authentication means anyone can access and can add users. Then i have tried to make it secure with different combinations like..

```
{5281, ejabberd_http, [
    http_bind,
    http_poll,
    web_admin,
    {access, configure, [{allow, admin}]}  %% actually admin has password
    {request_handlers, [
        {["register"], mod_register_web}
    ]}
]},
```

But it is still not asking for any password. While port 5280 for admin pages, is password protected. Can anyone guide how i can apply security on mod_register_web module like whenever anyone access through IP then it should prompt for username and password.

Comment: Why do you need mod_register_web then? Regular web admin allows adding users after entering the admin password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by modifying source code (mod_register_web.erl).

Like 'ejabberd_web_admin.erl', call get_auth_admin() and check result at the process().